# Missing import options to import qtcreator projectfile into Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt-creator

It should be possible, regarding to several threads like [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/21406-importing-creator-project-into-eclipse) one, to import QtCreator Projects into eclipse by doing File->Import->Qt Project.

This Option doesn´t exists in my Eclipse IDE (Version: 3.7.2).

Do I need additional plugins to Import QtCreator plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokia provided (for Qt version 4) a Qt integration plugin for eclipse. But they stopped the development since Qt version 5.